# There is a lot of people

Tags: word-choice

Is it true that either "there is" or "there's" works in these sentences  but when I have a plural noun such as "students", "people" or "doctors" only "there's" is natural not "there is"? In sentences 2, 4, 6, 7,8

1. There's a cat on the table.
2. There's two cats on the table.
3. There's a cat and three dogs under the table.
4. There's two cats and three dogs under the table.
5. There's a student waiting for you.
6. There's six students waiting for you.
7. There's a lot of people here.
8. There's seven people on the list.

Comment: Plural nouns should be followed by are instead of is. Instead of *there's*, you could use *they're* or there are.

Comment: @UnrealApex Surely, you mean *there're* rather than *they're*. And please reconsider the meaning of "followed" in this context.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney - sadly, many native speakers confuse _their_, _there_, and _they're_.

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo, I do mean there're.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard English, we use 'there are' with plural nouns:

> There are three men in the car
>
> There are many people in the boat
>
> There are six dogs, three cats, and one bird in the garden.

However, in casual speech, native speakers may often ignore this and say *there is* or *there's*. To do this is informal and non-standard. When I was at school teachers told us not to this, and it would be marked as an error in written work. So in standard English, only 1 and 5 of your numbered examples are correct.

> In speaking and in some informal writing, we use there’s even when it
> refers to more than one. This use could be considered incorrect in
> formal writing or in an examination
>
> There’s three other people who are still to come.
>
> There’s lots of cars in the car park.

[There is, there's, there are (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/there-is-there-s-and-there-are)

Despite what Cambridge Dictionary says, many careful native speakers will correctly use *there are* in speech as well as writing.

You should be aware that *there's* is a contraction of *there is* and has the same meaning.